# how to solve race condition involving behavior subject and async function?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an async function that is called multiple times simultaneously, and I am assuming calling `.next(true)` on a behavior subject is also asynchronous, therefore when multiple calls to this function happen simultaneously the value returned from `await firstValueFrom(this.isBusy$);` in the subsequent calls are still false, even though `.next(true)` was called via the initial function caller.

How can I make it so that subsequent calls will properly reflect the correct `isBusy$` value?

I have made a stackblitz to illustrate my problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-wrw3h6?file=index.ts

Also I should note, although I made the stackblitz not involve Angular, the code is actually from an Angular HTTP Interceptor, where it would be doing:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {

  let headers: AuthorizationHeaders;
  const getAuthorizationHeader = async () => {
    headers = await this.authService.headers();
  };

  return from(getAuthorizationHeader()).pipe(
    switchMap(() => next.handle(request.clone({
      setHeaders: headers,
    })))
  );
}
```

And the problem is, because it's never knowing that the auth call is busy, it's calling to get a refresh token repeatedly when there are multiple components on the page making api calls simultaneously.

So the question is, how can I make it so that a bunch of api calls are made, but only one call to refresh a token is made, and all other ones wait until the token call is completed before it returns the authorization header?

Comment: Why awaiting `firstValueFrom(this.isBusy$)` and not using `this.isBusySubject.value` on line 20?

Comment: aha.. that solved the problem..  If you make it an answer I will accept it.  Thank you.

Comment: that's great, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BehaviorSubject works in synchronous fashion. Instead of using `await firstValueFrom(this.isBusy$)` use `this.isBusySubject.value`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix promises and RxJs. Expose the header as an observable.

```
headers$ = isBusy$.pipe(
  filter(isBusy => !isBusy),
  switchMap(() => {
    if (this.isTokenExpired) {
      this.isBusySubject.next(true);
      return getTokenCall().pipe(
        tap(token) => {
          this.token = token;
          this.isBusySubject.next(false);
        }),
        map(token => (({ Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}` })))
      );
    } else {
      return of({ Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}` });
    }
  })
)
```

Then you just return the observable from the service in your interceptor.

About behavior subjects being completely synchronous.

```js
const { BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;

const bs$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);

bs$.subscribe(val => { console.log('Emitting ' + val); });

console.log('Calling next on 1');
bs$.next(1);
console.log('Calling next on 2');
bs$.next(2);
console.log('Calling next on 3');
bs$.next(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

putting a delay on them makes the asynchronous and will queue them for execution

```js
const { BehaviorSubject, delay } = rxjs;

const bs$ = new BehaviorSubject(0);

bs$.pipe(delay()).subscribe(val => { console.log('Emitting ' + val); });

console.log('Calling next on 1');
bs$.next(1);
console.log('Calling next on 2');
bs$.next(2);
console.log('Calling next on 3');
bs$.next(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```